# WinForms dataBinding triggers 2 times CheckedChanged event and makes the checkBox unclickable

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

The code below is from a simple test application containing just one checkbox on the form.

```
DataTable dt;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dt = new DataTable(); 
    dt.Columns.Add("bool", typeof(bool));
    dt.Columns.Add("s", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[2] { false, "" });
    checkBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", dt, "bool", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation);
    checkBox1.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_CheckedChanged;
}

private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt.Rows[0]["s"] = "test";
}
```

This line `dt.Rows[0]["s"] = "test";`
makes the checkbox unclickable. The CheckedChanged is triggered 2 times. The first time after responding to the click event. The second time being called by external code showing in the stack the CurrencyManager and BindingManagerBase.PushData.

If I remove this line or run it in a timer, the behavior of the checkBox is normal.

Comment: Change binding to `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the data source update mode to `OnPropertyChanged`.

When the data source update mode is on `OnValidation`, when `CheckedChanged` happens, the value is still not written to data source, because no validation has happened. So data source still has the previous check state. Then after you change a value on the data source, no matter what column you update, data bindings try to push latest values of the current records to controls. That's why the checked value will not change and always show the value of the bool column of the current row.

You can also try this while keeping data source update mode as `OnValidation`:

```
checkBox1.DataBindings["Checked"].WriteValue();
dt.Rows[0]["s"] = "test";
```

Which basically do the same thing as setting update mode to `OnPropertyChanged`.

Comment: _no matter what column you update, data bindings try to push latest values of the current records to controls_ - this is a key knowledge when try to use MVVM approach in Winforms